# how to efficienlty do dataframe shift with a jump

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, shift, execution-time

I have 60 log files that I am analysis. From those files I created the dataframe `state_n_ev_mat`. Its size is **`[2083656 rows x 8 columns]`**. Below you can see the first 50 rows of `state_n_ev_mat`.

Where, `block` identifies each file, `ts` is the current timeslot, `n_ts` are the next 24 open timeslots for the current `ts`. `n_cp` is the clearing price that ocurred in `ts` for `n_ts`, `c_cp` the clearing price of previous `ts` for `n_ts`. For the moment don't consider the rest of the columns.

What I'm trying to do is to populate `c_cp` with the clearing prices of the previous `ts`. Except for the very first 24 since there was no activity prior to that.

For example, the `c_cp` value of `row 24` (i.e. 27.9) is the value of `n_cp` in `row 1`. It is basically a shift up to the 23rd value since the 24th `n_ts` wasn't open in the previous `ts`, but discarding the initial `n_cp` value since that `ts` is no longer open in the next `ts`.

What I mean with the latter is that in `ts=361` the `n_ts=361` is no longer available.

In few words, `c_cp` is populated from the previous 23 data points in `n_cp` leaving the 24th as `NaN`.

Does this makes sense?

My attempt is:

```
 for m in range(60):
    last_current = last_ts[m]-24
    for n in range(360,last_current):
        state_n_ev_mat.c_cp.loc[(state_n_ev_mat.block==m) & (state_n_ev_mat.ts==n+1)] = \
            state_n_ev_mat.n_cp.loc[(state_n_ev_mat.block==m) & (state_n_ev_mat.ts==n)].shift(-1).values
```

This approach is taking a lot of time to finish. **So far it is computing the 56th block and the running time is 18 hrs.**

**Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks**

Below the first 50 rows of `state_n_ev_mat`, after one loop of the inner `for`.

```
   block   ts  n_ts  n_cp  c_cp  c_w  f_w  p_w
0      0  360 361.0  27.5   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1      0  360 362.0  27.9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2      0  360 363.0  27.9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3      0  360 364.0  27.7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4      0  360 365.0  34.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5      0  360 366.0  33.9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6      0  360 367.0  34.1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7      0  360 368.0  33.7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8      0  360 369.0  40.3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9      0  360 370.0  40.1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
10     0  360 371.0  50.1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11     0  360 372.0  40.1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
12     0  360 373.0  44.4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
13     0  360 374.0 106.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
14     0  360 375.0  74.9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
15     0  360 376.0  95.4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
16     0  360 377.0 125.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
17     0  360 378.0 139.1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
18     0  360 379.0 133.3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
19     0  360 380.0 124.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
20     0  360 381.0 139.1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
21     0  360 382.0  53.1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
22     0  360 383.0  45.1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
23     0  360 384.0  46.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
24     0  361 362.0  36.4  27.9  NaN  NaN  NaN
25     0  361 363.0  31.8  27.9  NaN  NaN  NaN
26     0  361 364.0  31.2  27.7  NaN  NaN  NaN
27     0  361 365.0  33.4  34.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
28     0  361 366.0  34.2  33.9  NaN  NaN  NaN
29     0  361 367.0   0.0  34.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
30     0  361 368.0   0.0  33.7  NaN  NaN  NaN
31     0  361 369.0   0.0  40.3  NaN  NaN  NaN
32     0  361 370.0   0.0  40.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
33     0  361 371.0   0.0  50.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
34     0  361 372.0   0.0  40.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
35     0  361 373.0   0.0  44.4  NaN  NaN  NaN
36     0  361 374.0   0.0 106.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
37     0  361 375.0   0.0  74.9  NaN  NaN  NaN
38     0  361 376.0   0.0  95.4  NaN  NaN  NaN
39     0  361 377.0   0.0 125.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
40     0  361 378.0   0.0 139.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
41     0  361 379.0   0.0 133.3  NaN  NaN  NaN
42     0  361 380.0   0.0 124.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
43     0  361 381.0   0.0 139.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
44     0  361 382.0   0.0  53.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
45     0  361 383.0   0.0  45.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
46     0  361 384.0   0.0  46.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
47     0  361 385.0  46.2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
48     0  362 363.0  39.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
49     0  362 364.0  33.1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a better understanding..

```
#get number of chunks
chunks =  -(-len(frame) // 24)
#create chunks
groups = [frame.iloc[x*24:x*24+24,:].copy() for x in range(0,chunks)]

for i in range(0,len(groups)):
    if i == 0:
        groups[i]['c_cp'] = np.nan
    else:
        if len(groups[i]) < 24:
            groups[i]['c_cp'] = np.nan
        else:
            data = groups[i-1]['n_cp'].tolist()
            data = data[1:]
            data.append(np.nan)
            groups[i]['c_cp'] = data

print pd.concat(groups)
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. because there is always sort of a jump. Please bear with me. Let say we make chunks of 24 rows each of the entire dataframe 'state_n_ev_mat'. Then, each chunk of the new col 'c_cp' is populated with the 23 rows of the previous chunk of 'n_cp'. There are two things happening here: first, the last element of that chunk of 'c_cp' remains unpopulated, i.e., 'NaN'. And secondly, since we are only considering the previous 23 rows, the first element of the 'n_cp' chunk is discarded. Does this makes sense?

Comment: @Arraval I have updated the code to include the jumps, the last chunk is a mystery tho, so in the code if the chunk is less than 24 elements long it gets all NaN values, if that's wrong I can update, but it is how you showed it in your example. Also I test on a dataframe 10000 lines long and it finishes fast

Comment: impressive, that's just amazing. It's super fast!! Finished the computation in less than 5 mins